# How do I unlink SuperSU from the Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store, supersu

I installed SuperSU by flashing the zip file from recovery. The Play Store picks it up and shows new versions of the app. The problem is, the newer versions of SuperSU causes my phone to go into a boot loop. I have already disabled auto updates for SuperSU but I want to go the extra mile and completely unlink it from Play Store so it doesn't show up in the list of apps with updates available. That way, I won't accidentally update it.

Titanium Backup has the functionality to do this but for some reason SuperSU doesn't show up in the app list on TB.

Comment: It shows up in TiBu - SU version 2.79

Comment: is that a different version? I don't see it on the play store

Comment: You see 2.82 ( Chainfire Super SU), mine was installed much before and I rarely update apps once installed ( unless they add a new feature which I want) so my updates are globally turned off. Maybe you can Google and download the earlier version and check if it appears in your TiBU

Comment: Here is a link https://www.supersuroot.com/download.html

Comment: Even if you manage to unlink it, it will show up (relink) again shortly (Play Services take care for that). So you'ld need a scheduled task unlinking it every 24h or so. We had that already as general question here a while ago, with exactly that solution, see [How to get rid of update notifications for a given app in Google Play Store?](/q/58021/16575)

Comment: @beeshyams oh, that's what you meant, I've already downgraded to the version that works on my phone (which coincidentally is 2.79) but yeah, that doesn't shoe up.

Comment: @Izzy that's sucks, I didn't want to use Tasker. I'll check out the other solutions posted there. I didn't know the Titanium Backup method is no longer permanent.

Comment: @user400424 who said Tasker? TiBu has a built-in scheduler you can use for that. And it's already for quite a while that the "unlink" is no longer permanent, a couple of years at least.